# How to add 2D with every layers of 3D while True

Tags: python, arrays, 3d, 2d

I do have 3 arrays.

```
a = [[0 1] [2 3]]
b = [[True False] [True False]]
c = [[[1 1] [1 1] [1 1] [1 1]][[1 1] [1 1] [1 1] [1 1]]]
```

`a` is 2D array containing numbers.
`b` is 2D array containing True or False statements.
`c` is 3D array containing numbers.

let say `c` has 2 layers of 2D array and I would like to add `a` with every layer of `c` as long as `b` is True. Is there any way to do it without using the loop for every cell in python?

expected result

```
k = [[2 1] [4 3]]
```

Comment: Plz post what code you have implemented, so it can be optimised to work efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers. I think I found the answer that I want.

```
k = np.where(b,a+c.sum(axis = 1),a+0).
```